# Terraform cloud_sql_instance "connection_name" field cannot be set

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am attempting to create a google cloud sql instance with Terraform. When defining the `connection_name` argument under the `google_sql_database_instance` resource I receive the following error when I run `terraform apply`:

```
Error: google_sql_database_instance.sql_instance: "connection_name": this field cannot be set
```

My Terraform block:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql_instance" {
  name             = "${var.sql_name}"
  region           = "${var.region}"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_9_6"
  connection_name  = "${data.google_project.my_project.project_id}:${var.region}:${var.sql_name}"
  project          = "${data.google_project.my_project.project_id}"

  settings {
    tier      = "db-custom-6-23040"
    disk_size = "${var.sql_disk_size}"
    disk_type = "${var.sql_disk_type}"
  }
}
```

Removing the `connection_name` argument results in a successful `plan`, and removing all `:` from the value as well as hard coding the string results in a failure as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection_name` parameter for `google_sql_database_instance` is only meant to be read, not set by the user.

As such you shouldn't be trying to set it and instead you will only need it when passing the output to another resource or an output like this:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "sql_instance" {
  name             = "${var.sql_name}"
  region           = "${var.region}"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_9_6"
  project          = "${data.google_project.my_project.project_id}"

  settings {
    tier      = "db-custom-6-23040"
    disk_size = "${var.sql_disk_size}"
    disk_type = "${var.sql_disk_type}"
  }
}

output "connection_name" {
  value = "${google_sql_database_instance.sql_instance.connection_name}"
}
```

Comment: I've also raised a pull request to fix the docs: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/pull/1650

Comment: thanks! i was translating some gdm scripts that a predecessor wrote and you are able to set it via that

Comment: I don't know much about Google Cloud but if you think it would be useful to set it to something other than what you get given by default then the pull request should be pretty simple. It looked at a quick glance that the SDK allowed for it but the original PR that added the attribute seemed to be just using it for exporting the attribute and never setting it.